# how to check cookie and redirect in typo3

Tags: redirect, cookies, typo3

I'm trying to check the presence of a cookie and redirect from Typo3, but not having any luck.  Does anyone have an example of how a cookie could be tested and the user redirected based on the presence either using PHP or Typoscript?

Answer (score 3):

Try this typoscript:

`[globalVar = _COOKIE|myCookie = 1]`

`//your code`

`[else]`

`page.config >`

`page.config.additionalHeaders = Location: http://www.yourdomain.org/login.html`

`[end]`

Have a nice day !!

Answer (score 0):

If you want to check on general cookie support, try this:

```
[globalString = TSFE:fe_user|cookieId = /\w{32}/]
page.10 >
page.10 = TEXT
page.10.value = Your browser looks like supporting cookies, yeah ;-)
[global]
```

I think it'll only works properly on the second page the user visits, when the presumable FE cookie has already been tried storing.